# Geometry Dash, How to change already set up account name?

Tags: geometry-dash

I have already went on the settings in geometry dash and went on account and set up a account with the name of xSnowyMinx, after a while I didn't like that name and I wanted to change it. So I started looking around trying to find a setting where you can change a already set up account name on the settings... no luck.... I cannot find a place and I was wondering if you can or can not change it??

Note: It's an official setup account so that means you can't change it in the Character Selection where you click on the name and change it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your registered username once by going to account/more/account manager.

This will bring up the user managment page, log in with your current Geometry Dash user and password, click "Change Username" and enter the new username you want to have.

Comment: I done all of that then it brings me up to a website called account management, what do I do then to change my name???

Comment: Go to [the account management page](http://www.boomlings.com/database/accounts/accountManagement.php) and log in with the password and username created in Geometry Dash. Click on "Change username" and enter your new desired username and hit 'Change Username'.

Answer (score -1):

It's an official account setup, which means you cannot change it in the Character Selection where you'd normally be able to click on the name and change it.